# $httpBackend expectGET not returning expected data

Tags: angularjs, promise, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I will just start out saying that $httpBackend and spyOn are pretty new to me, and I am struggling to get a clear picture of what is happening.  Basically, I'm trying to do an *$httpBackend.expectGET('/myroute/').respond(...)* and then use *spyOn*, but I keep getting

```
Expected [  ] to equal Object({ success: true, message: 'Yeah!' })
```

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
angular.module('TestModule')
       .service('TestService',TestService);

TestService.$inject = ['$http'];
function TestService($http){
    var service = {};
    service.DoIt = DoIt;
    return service;

    function DoIt() {
        return $http.get('/myroute/')
            .then(handleSuccess,handleError('Error happened!'));
    }

    function handleSuccess(res) {
        return res.data;
    }

    function handleError(error) {
        return function(){
            return {success: false, message: error}
        };
    }
}
```

Here's my Karma-Jasmine test:

```
describe('Test Module',function(){
    beforeEach(module('TestModule'));

    describe('TestService Tests',function(){
        var service,$httpBackend;
        beforeEach(inject([
             '$injector',
             function($injector){
                 $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
                 service = $injector.get('TestService');
             }
        ]));

        afterEach(function(){
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('should DoIt',function(){
            var mockResponse = {
                data : {success:true, message:"Yeah!"}
            };

            $httpBackend.expectGET('/myroute')
                        .respond(Promise.resolve(mockResponse));

            spyOn(service,'DoIt').and.callThrough();

            service.DoIt().then(function(data){
                expect(service.DoIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(data).toEqual(mockResponse.data); <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE -->
            });

            $httpBackend.flush();
        });

    });
});
```

Further information:

Using the example I found here: http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/26/unit-testing-http-ngmock-fundamentals/, I tried this in my test code:

```
it('should DoIt',inject(function($http){
    var promise = $http.get('/myroute').then(handleSuccess,handleError('bad stuff happened'));
    promise.then(function(data){
        console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data,null,3));
    });

    $httpBackend.expect('GET','/myroute').respond(200,{data:'Yeah!'});
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));

function handleSuccess(response) {return response.data;}
function handleError(error){
    return function(){
        return {success:false,message:error};
    };
}
```

This gives me the response that I expect: 'Data: {"data": "yeah"}'

My updated question: I thought service.DoIt() was doing the same thing as the promise.  What is going on here?  Am I not injecting my service?  I do not understand how Karma expects me to stage this test.  Any help, please!

Comment: @jbrown - I guess this is where the syntax gets me.  I thought I was passing it in.  I thought my $httpBackend.expectGET('/myroute').respond(...) was taking care of the $http.get('/myroute') in DoIt().  I thought my mockResponse would then be passed to handleSuccess() and it had a 'data' property.  But that's not what is happening here?

Comment: That just sets 'data' to undefined.

Comment: Also, since you brought it up, what problems are you seeing with the service code?  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intention with the test correctly, I believe this is what you need:

```
describe('Test Module', function() {

    var $httpBackend, service;

    beforeEach(module('TestService'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _TestService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        service = _TestService_;
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should DoIt', function() {
        var mockResponse = {
            data: { success: true, message: "Yeah!" }
        };

        $httpBackend.expectGET('/myroute/')
            .respond(mockResponse);

        service.DoIt().then(function(data) {
            expect(data).toEqual(mockResponse);
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

});
```

Comment: This gives me "Expected [  ] to equal Object({ data: Object({ success: true, message: 'Yeah!' }) })", which is the same error I was getting before.  Basically, this "solution" changes the injection syntax.  According to Angular's API, both of our injection syntax's are legitimate.

Comment: Basically, this "solution" passes on my machine using the code you pasted for your service.

Comment: It also fixes a typo in the route for your $httpBackend.expectGET

Comment: Then maybe I've got my karma.conf setup wrong?  What could be the difference, then?  I can add it if you think it might help.

Comment: OK, holy crap.  I've got my angular.module('TestModule').service('TestService',...) wrapped in a (function(){'use strict'; angular...  })();.  When I stripped off that function(),use strict wrapper, it worked like you said. I didn't think that would affect karma-jasmine like that.

Comment: I'm just losing my mind.  I must not have hit CTRL-S, or something.  Regardless, your solution works.  Sorry for not paying close enough attention.  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, don't get hung up on the different injector style, I just wrote a test very quickly from scratch and copy/pasted. The code within the `it` function is where the magic is...

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was `transformResponse` function on `$resource` that modified the expected mock data:

`var resource = $resource('api/data/:id', {}, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function (data) {
        var d = angular.fromJson(data);
        return d.members;
      }
    }
...`

My mock data didn't contain memebers...